# Send SMS Verification Link problem with Automation

Tags: automation, sms, preview, confirm

I have simple automation that send to my customer a link via SMS for confirm order, this is mandatary because is Cash on Delivery order and I need to check if order is real (otherwhise I must lost time to call and confirm manually)

So the problem is the new SmartPhone open automatically link via sms, maybe for show the preview of the website, I not have idea and this cause the automatically confirmation because start automation.....I really not know how solve this

Comment: I not want send via EMAIL because in Italy 80% people are digitally backward and can't even use email, or credit card

Comment: my php code just take the $_GET variable and check if exist into order
If yes order is confirmed
If no the automation is blocked

but via sms open automatically the link....